# Including SendGrid breaks compile

Tags: .net, sendgrid

I've just downloaded SendGrid via Nuget and am trying to use it in one of my projects in a Solution.

I have the following references:

[image]

And referenced in my file:

[image]

And this code:

[image]

But I get the error "The type or namespace name 'SendGridMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)":

[image]

What's wrong with the above?

Comment: Note for people like me who came here for similar error, check your code is up to date, because the code I got from MSDN is way out of date and also produces the 'namespace name 'SendGridMessage' could not be found' error, see https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp for up to date code.

Answer (score 6):

SendGrid has now added a fork to nuget for .Net 4.0 support. If you want to keep using .Net 4.0 then you can install the SendGrid.Net40 package using the Visual Studio NuGet Console Manager with the following line:

```
Install-Package SendGrid.Net40
```

Here is the link to SendGrid that mentions that it has been forked:
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/112

and a link to the SendGrid.Net4.0 NuGet Gallery:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SendGrid.Net40/

Comment: Correct they have done this only so that people can still function in .Net 4.0

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it needs .NET Framework 4.5, not 4.0 as the documentation says.

=========== EDIT: ===========

In response to @bwest's comment, here's what I tried:

Empty console app, .NET Framework V4:

[image]

Switch to .NET Framework v4.5:

[image]

Comment: That's not the case. I've just now created a new NET40 project, added the SendGrid nuget package, and compiled without issue.

Comment: @bwest - I get the above behaviour. Have I downloaded a different nuget version that requires 4.5? I can't get it to build/compile in v4.

Comment: Oof, my mistake. Sorry! Last version had a bug in it and has been unlisted. 3.0.2 should work.

Answer (score 0):

Following a tutorial on Microsoft, I run into this same problem. I googled around and foun the solution in [this github forum](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/315)

Basically its suggesting installing the correct SendGrid API version from NuGet. So in my case what finally resolved the issue is when I uninstalled the latest and installed **V2 API** (Install-Package Sendgrid -Version 6.3.4)