# "The primary reference could not be resolved...." error - which package should I use?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, sendgrid

I have an MVC5 application which targets .NET Framework 4.5 & am trying to use `SendGrid` NuGet package `8.0.4.0`

I'm getting this build error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning     The primary reference "SendGrid, Version=8.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4f047e93159395ca, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5".   App.ServiceLayer

I have tried using SendGrid `8.0.0.0` but get the same error.

**How can I find out which version I can use with .NET 4.5?**

I have looked at the SendGrid NuGet package gallery [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sendgrid/) but I can't see any information about the target framework

Comment: I found this article:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242059/including-sendgrid-breaks-compile
basically states to install SendGrid.Net40 instead of SendGrid <version>
Worth a try, it seems to have worked for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing  the list version of SendGrid NuGet package, I found that the 6.3.4 version supports .NET Framework 4.5. Other versions that higher than 6.3.4 are support .NET Framework 4.5.2.

So please choose the SendGrid 6.3.4 for your .NET Framework 4.5 project.